# android opengl set bitmap to sprite

Tags: android, opengl-es

im trying to set a new bitmap to a sprite every 2 seconds. The code im using requires a GL10 object but can not be done in onDraw() because it reduces the framerate too much. I tried  setting a gl object to equal the one passed in onSurfaceCreated(), but it doesnt work. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allocate all your textures in `onSurfaceCreated()`, create a `Texture` object (which contains a `GL` pointer for your texture) and assign that loaded texture (from `OpenGL` memory) to your `Texture` object's `GL` pointer id.

Later, in `onDrawFrame()`, just change `glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureObjectId)` to `glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, anotherTextureObjectId)`.

This is how you change a texture without allocating during runtime using simple images/sprites.